# Getting the index of the substring on solaris

Tags: regex, bash, solaris

How can I find the index of a substring which matches a regular expression on solaris10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goto options for me are bash, awk and perl. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but any of the three would likely work well. For example:

```
f=somestring
string=$(expr match "$f" '.*\(expression\).*')
echo $string
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that what you want is to find the location of the first match of a wildcard in a string using bash, the following bash function returns just that, or empty if the wildcard doesn't match:

```
function match_index()
{
  local pattern=$1
  local string=$2  
  local result=${string/${pattern}*/}

  [ ${#result} = ${#string} ] || echo ${#result}
}
```

For example:

```
$ echo $(match_index "a[0-9][0-9]" "This is a a123 test")
10
```

If you want to allow full-blown regular expressions instead of just wildcards, replace the "local result=" line with

```
local result=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/'"$pattern"'.*$//')
```

but then you're exposed to the usual shell quoting issues.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question as bash, so I'm going to assume you're asking how to do this in a bash script. Unfortunately, the built-in regular expression matching doesn't save string indices. However, if you're asking this in order to extract the match substring, you're in luck:

```
if [[ "$var" =~ "$regex" ]]; then
     n=${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
     while [[ $i -lt $n ]]
     do
         echo "capture[$i]: ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
        let i++
     done
fi
```

This snippet will output in turn all of the submatches. The first one (index 0) will be the entire match.

You might like your `awk` options better, though. There's a function `match` which gives you the index you want. Documentation can be found [here](http://people.cs.uu.nl/piet/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html). It'll also store the length of the match in `RLENGTH`, if you need that. To implement this in a bash script, you could do something like:

```
match_index=$(echo "$var_to_search" | \
awk '{
    where = match($0, '"$regex_to_find"')
    if (where)
        print where
    else
        print -1
}')
```

There are a lot of ways to deal with passing the variables in to awk. This combination of piping output and directly embedding one into the awk one-liner is fairly common. You can also give awk variable values with the `-v` option (see `man awk`).

Obviously you can modify this to get the length, the match string, whatever it is you need. You can capture multiple things into an array variable if necessary:

```
match_data=($( ... awk '{ ... print where,RLENGTH,match_string ... }'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash 4.x you can source the oobash. A string lib written in bash with oo-style:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/oobash/

String is the constructor function:

> String a abcda
>
> a.indexOf a
>
> 0
>
> a.lastIndexOf a
>
> 4
>
> a.indexOf da
>
> 3

There are many "methods" more to work with strings in your scripts:

```
-base64Decode      -base64Encode  -capitalize        -center            
-charAt            -concat        -contains          -count             
-endsWith          -equals        -equalsIgnoreCase  -reverse           
-hashCode          -indexOf       -isAlnum           -isAlpha           
-isAscii           -isDigit       -isEmpty           -isHexDigit        
-isLowerCase       -isSpace       -isPrintable       -isUpperCase       
-isVisible         -lastIndexOf   -length            -matches           
-replaceAll        -replaceFirst  -startsWith        -substring         
-swapCase          -toLowerCase   -toString          -toUpperCase       
-trim              -zfill
```